# Position sticky fails on flex element on Chrome

Tags: css-position, flexbox, sticky

I'm trying to set a flex element to `position: sticky` using this library:

https://github.com/soenkekluth/sticky-state

I have a very simple layout with a flex container and two columns inside. I want the right column to be sticky.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">bla</div>
  <div class="right sticky">sticky</div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5%;
}

.left {
  background: green;
  flex: 2;
  height: 3000px;
  margin-right: 3em;
  width: 80%;
}

.right {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;  
  top: 5em;
  width: 400px;
}
```

Here's a pen illustrating the whole thing: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LZVbPQ

On Firefox and Safari it works as expected, or at least as I want it to work. On Chrome it doesn't. Any idea why?